# So can someone tell me what's wrong with the question I posted below?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

so I posted a question here, [Battery discharging while plugged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395893/battery-discharging-while-plugged-in)

and it was closed for being similar, which I don't think it is besides being battery related...  I was told I could edit it and it would be re considered.  I did, but apparently not enough.  I was told I could redo it and I did and they it was closed for being a duplicate.  What gives?  Any help appreciated.  Stumpded.

from c/s email.....

Ok, now I’m thoroughly confused -

My question was closed as being associated with other question - but, it was not the same in symptoms and the other question is still open and not confirmed as solved.  Its marked as answered but not confirmed as solving the issue.  So, it did not address the issues I am having.

- my 1st question was marked as having private feedback - where is it?  I can’t find it.
- I was told I could edit the question and it would be submitted for reopening.  I did, but got no response.
- I was told I could submit the question again.  I did.  Then it was flagged as a duplicate.  So, why tell me to submit it and change then flag and close it again?
- I’ve reviewed the question guidelines and for the life of me can’t see what the problem is.  Can someone tell me please?

Tks

Comment: There’s nothing at all wrong with a closed question and duplicates. We love them and I tend to vote up any question clear enough to be a duplicate since they steer people to the primary answers for a given topic.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reaching out on Meta to have this clarified. I see two main topics here, first the reposting of a "on hold" question, second the "on hold" of the first question itself.

**Regarding the reposting**:

- You posted [Battery charge status decreases while plugged in charging](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395867/battery-charge-status-decreases-while-plugged-in-charging) initially which got put on hold for being a duplicate of an older question
- You reposted basically the same question again as [Battery discharging while plugged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395893/battery-discharging-while-plugged-in)

If you don't agree with the hold of a question, it's preferable to edit the  question and address the "on hold" reasons directly. This ensures that any comments added to the question remain visible to all reviewers so everybody has the full picture. This also means that your edits actually need to be substantial and *address* the issues. From looking at the history of the first question I don't see any edit at all, so it rather looks like you reposted directly. That repost was correctly closed as a duplicate again.

**Regarding the duplicate:**

Generally speaking we tend to close as duplicate if a question can be answered by an already existing answer. Said answer doesn't need to be accepted, it doesn't even need to have upvotes, but it should provide a reasonable explanation to your question as well. In your case the relevant part most probably is

> As of Catalina (10.15.5) Apple has implemented a feature called Battery Health Management that will stop charging and allow it to discharge to a predetermined charge (about 80%) before recharging again. This happens even while the charger is plugged in and working.

This may or may not be applicable in your case, we just don't have enough information to decide. But right now it provides a valid answer for your question (*"What would cause this? Ideas? Does anyone else have a MBP that decreases the battery charge while plugged?"*). It also could be caused by the OEM adapter, or the battery could be faulty, but right now we don't have enough information. And while we can't expect users to be electrician or subject matter experts in whatever they are asking, we do expect them to do basic analysis and triage to clarify issues.

Now if you can show that the charge drops significantly below 80% while being plugged in (and edit that into the question), and that it also occurs with the Apple adapter, this would be a reason for reopening it as the answer obviously doesn't fit any more.

---

To give specific answers to your specific questions:

> my 1st question was marked as having private feedback - where is it? I can’t find it.

The only private feedback in this case is "A community member has associated this post with a similar question." in the blue box on top of your question. I agree that in case of dupes this isn't all that helpful, for other "on hold" reasons there usually are more details. But as you did, comments can always be used to clarify holds.

> I was told I could edit the question and it would be submitted for reopening. I did, but got no response.

According to the change history you didn't (or you tried to but the system didn't store your edit). In general when on hold questions get edited they get placed into a review queue for reopenings. It may take several hours or even a day to get reviewed.

> I was told I could submit the question again. I did. Then it was flagged as a duplicate. So, why tell me to submit it and change then flag and close it again?

Didn't see a recommendation to resubmit, only to edit. If I have missed this somehow, please explain.

Comment: So I had a comment that there was private feedback but did not know where to look for it. It’s unclear to me that the message right there that it was closed was the private feedback. As I did not know how to check status of resubmission, I emailed help. They told me that an edit automatically starts the process. I did an edit but saw no reaction. They someone commented my edit was too I significant so I posted again as I. The same email I mentioned fro help, I believe they said I could do that too. Hence the “dup”.   I don’t have Battery Management on and as far as I can tell my problem is dif

Comment: @Stumped I've edited your question a bit, let's continue the content discussion there.

Comment: Roger that. tks

Comment: @nohillside prompts re edit or ask again see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951/136010 for possible reason

Comment: @mmmmmm The „duplicate“ message is different, it doesn‘t suggest to post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Just as a personal opinion based on my observations, there are too many questions closed as being "duplicates" here. Some duplicate classifications seem to border on ludicrous - again, my opinion. I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: Ok...I’m not saying your position is invalid but this post isn’t very helpful,  can you supply examples with rationale supporting your position?  The model we use ultimately comes down to humans making choices and even with democratic process being employed, mistakes are often made.  Things get reversed all the time...so what specifically are you referring to?

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a detailed discussion about one or two examples. I believe I made it clear that: a) it was my opinion, and b) based on my observationS. If you don't have similar observations, then I'm not quite sure why you've bothered to downvote & comment.